# Jquery: Delay before triggering Supersized function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, delay, supersized

I have a page that has a lot of animations on it, as well as the Supersized plugin 9large background image carousel). It seems that loading the background image for the Supersized function disrupts my animations a little, making them jerky.

I am wondering if anyone knows of a way to delay the triggering of a function? EG:

```
jQuery(function($).delay('1000'){

    $.supersized({

//Functionality
slideshow:1,        //Slideshow on/off
autoplay:1,     //Slideshow starts playing automatically
etc...
```

Ive tried combinations of the above to no effect.

My goal would be to have all my other animations completed before the plugin gets triggered.

Would anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can delay the execution of a function using setTimeout.

```
setTimeout( function() {
    $.supersized({});
}, 1000);
```

Not sure how you are animating your page, but If you are using any of the jQuery animation methods you can also try calling your supersized function from a callback. For example:

```
$('selector').animate({
    left: '+=50'
    }, 2000, function() {
        $.supersized({});
});
```

This will call your supersized function after the animation completes.